# Converting a number into a 5 value string or array having the format "00000"

Tags: php, arrays, counter

In PHP, I need to display a big 5 digit, graphical counter from a number fetched from a database. Examples:

- If number = 1, counter should display 00001
- If number = 15, counter should display 00015
- if number = 999, counter should display 00999

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: with sprintf("%05d", 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf` formats have a zero-padding option:

```
printf("%05d", $number);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`str_pad`](https://www.php.net/str_pad):

```
$output = str_pad ($input, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 1):

The versatile `printf` or `sprintf` for the value 1 as 00001:

```
printf('%05d', 1);
```